# Combine 2 dbExpressions

Tags: c#, entity-framework, expression

Is there a way to combine multiple dbExpressions into one expression?

I am using this guide to create a softdelete interceptor so I can filter out deleted items in one of my tables in my model.
http://marisks.net/2016/02/27/entity-framework-soft-delete-and-automatic-created-modified-dates/

the current visitor query is this

```
 var table = (EntityType)expression.Target.ElementType;
                if (table.Properties.All(p => p.Name != IsDeletedColumnName))
                {
                    return base.Visit(expression);
                }

                var binding = expression.Bind();

                return binding.Filter(
                    binding.VariableType.Variable(binding.VariableName).Property(IsDeletedColumnName).IsNull()

                    );
```

However I want to add another check to the Filter, so its not only checking if the deleted column is null but if another column is null.

Does anyone have enough experience with dbExpressions to help here as the docs online seem pretty sparse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh nevermind I discovered the .And() and .Or() methods on dbExpressions. I think these will work.